# iptables string match, some packets still getting through

Tags: centos, iptables, centos7

I'm using fail2ban to police plain text http packets (SSL offload being used with load balancer) using a header added by the load balancer. fail2ban is complaining that it is seeing ip addresses in logs AFTER it bans them but the packet count on iptables is increasing, how can they possible be slipping past?

My fail2ban log looks like this

```
2020-09-27 19:10:42,748 fail2ban.actions        [1744]: NOTICE  [jailprov] Ban 5.180.220.215
2020-09-27 19:11:34,478 fail2ban.actions        [1744]: NOTICE  [jailprov] 5.180.220.215 already banned
2020-09-27 19:12:08,097 fail2ban.actions        [1744]: NOTICE  [jailprov] 5.180.220.215 already banned
2020-09-27 19:12:21,119 fail2ban.actions        [1744]: NOTICE  [jailprov] 5.180.220.215 already banned
2020-09-27 19:12:50,088 fail2ban.actions        [1744]: NOTICE  [jailprov] 5.180.220.215 already banned
2020-09-27 19:13:08,609 fail2ban.actions        [1744]: NOTICE  [jailprov] 5.180.220.215 already banned
```

My iptables looks like this

```
[me@server log]# iptables -vnL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2917 packets, 368K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
2751K  199M fail2ban-default  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
2749K  198M fail2ban-default  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2952 packets, 530K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain fail2ban-default (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   18  6408 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 STRING match  "5.180.220.215" ALGO name bm TO 65535
   [other rules removed for brevity]
5499K  396M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

[image]

Comment: Are you comparing *"IP present somewhere in the reassembled TCP stream"* with *"IP present within a single packet"*?

Comment: Something is very wrong with your firewall. All of the relevant stuff that fail2ban should have added is missing. Did you omit firewall rules when pasting? Please don't do that. It makes it impossible to understand. Post the complete output of `iptables -vnL` with no omissions.

Comment: @MichaelHamptonThe only removed rules are for other banned IPs, they are identical with the exception of the IP address. It will be a hundred lines long, not really worth clogging up the post with. I'm quite well versed on how ACLs work in general so you'll just have to trust me there, what stuff is missing, it's definitely not the stuff I excluded? I have 20 servers running the same setup and all have identical iptables but only this one is seeing already banned IPs in logs.

Comment: Why are there two identical rules in the  INPUT chain? Seems odd for a single jail enabled.

Comment: @anx good question, this is something I (unwillingly) inherited makes no sense to me why they would both have packet count and why they'd be different. As for your first question, I think this would only catch it within a single packet but there should be no fragmentation happening anywhere near the http header.

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/sysconfig/iptables` had an invalid (and invisible) character within it somewhere, possible a windows style line ending instead of unix style. It was stopping iptables service from running. Rebuilding the file with simple copy paste and restarting iptables service resolved the issue. Quick note, if I include only fail2ban rules in `iptables -vnL` after the fix it is still identical to what I show in the original question.